# Merge MySQL SELECT statements

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I have the following table *tbl_crps*, note that the column *crp* occurs more than one time, but *id* and *starts_on* will always differ in records with the same *crp*.

```
id |  crp | starts_on  |
------------------
1  |  20  | 2020-02-09 |
2  |  31  | 2019-06-05 |
3  |  20  | 2018-01-10 |
4  |  31  | 2021-07-03 |
5  |  58  | 2022-01-01 |
6  |  58  | 2025-02-02 |
```

I need to exctract the records with the following conditions:

1. If for *crp* one or more records with past *starts_on* exist, then the one with the greatest id among those records with that *crp* (the ones with past date) must be returned
2. If for *crp* no records exist with past date, then the one with the greatest id among all the records with that *crp*

I can successfully select records matching the first condition with the following.

`SELECT * FROM tbl_crps 
AND id IN (SELECT MAX(b.id) FROM tbl_crps b WHERE b.starts_on <= "2020-10-02")`

Will return records with ids 3 and 2.

What I need to achieve is adding to the result those records which *starts_on* is not in the past and which *crp* is not in the first result set.

Is it possible? Maybe this way?

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_crps a
WHERE id IN (
     SELECT MAX(a.id) FROM tbl_crps a WHERE a.starts_on <= "2020-10-02" GROUP BY a.crp
 )
UNION
(
    SELECT * FROM tbl_crps b
        WHERE id IN (
             SELECT MAX(c.id) FROM tbl_crps c WHERE c.starts_on > "2020-10-02"
             AND c.crp NOT IN (
                  SELECT d.crp FROM tbl_crps d
                  WHERE id IN (
                       SELECT MAX(e.id) FROM tbl_crps e WHERE e.starts_on <= "2020-10-02" GROUP BY e.crp)
                   )
        )
)
```

I'm using MySQL 5.7

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
You should consider using [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenated values

Comment: So WHY are you using `max()` if the expected result is MORE than ONE `id`

Comment: "I need to get a list the maximum ids ignoring the dates only for those records." what does this mean? ignoring dates for what records?

Comment: Maybe I am not understanding the question

Comment: If you change `SELECT MAX(id)` to `SELECT id` you'll get the expected result.

Comment: @RiggsFolly the Injection is not pertinent.

Comment: @Barmar no, it doesn't

Comment: @SEarle1986 I'll try to write the post again

Comment: Can we reopen this, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Akina's answer to my new question (this was closed), this does the job.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60156602/3872998

```
SELECT id, crp, starts_on
FROM tbl_crps
NATURAL JOIN (SELECT crp, MAX(id) id
              FROM tbl_crps
              WHERE starts_on < CURRENT_DATE
              GROUP BY crp) x
UNION ALL
SELECT id, crp, starts_on
FROM tbl_crps
NATURAL JOIN (SELECT crp, MAX(id) id
              FROM tbl_crps
              GROUP BY crp
              HAVING MIN(starts_on) >= CURRENT_DATE) x;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=acb7a67d2f4c62e3a8301d3137227d7f)

**My solution (not performant)**

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_crps a
WHERE id IN (
     SELECT MAX(a.id) FROM tbl_crps a WHERE a.starts_on <= "2020-10-02"
 )
UNION
(
    SELECT * FROM tbl_crps b
        WHERE id IN (
             SELECT MAX(c.id) FROM tbl_crps c WHERE c.starts_on > "2020-10-02"
             AND c.crp NOT IN (
                  SELECT d.crp FROM tbl_crps d
                  WHERE id IN (
                       SELECT MAX(e.id) FROM tbl_crps e WHERE e.starts_on <= "2020-10-02")
                   )
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your requirements completely, but I think this query does what you're looking for, or is very close to it:

```
WITH cteData AS (SELECT b.CRP, MAX(b.ID) AS ID
                   FROM tbl_crps b
                   WHERE b.starts_on <= "2020-10-02"
                   GROUP BY b.CRP)
SELECT *
  FROM tbl_crps a
  WHERE a.ID IN (SELECT ID
                   FROM (SELECT b.CRP, b.ID
                           FROM cteData b
                         UNION
                         SELECT d.CRP, d.ID
                           FROM tbl_crps d
                           WHERE d.starts_on > "2020-10-02" AND
                                 d.CRP NOT IN (SELECT crp
                                                 FROM cteData)) c)
```

This returns

```
id  crp starts_on
2   31  2019-06-05
3   20  2018-01-10
5   58  2022-01-01
6   58  2025-02-02
```

which seems to be correct based on my understanding of the requirements. In short

```
1 - NOT included because its date is in the past ('current' date = 2020-10-02) 
    and its ID is NOT the greatest among records in the past with that CRP.
2 - included because its date is in the past and its ID is the greatest
    among records with that CRP which have dates in the past.
3 - date is in the past, ID is greatest for that CRP with date in the past
4 - NOT included because date is in the future, but CRP is included in recs
    from first subquery.
5 - date is in the future, and CRP does not occur in first subquery
6 - date is in the future, and CRP does not occur in first subquery
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=673f19789e503cbc904d28c49f1ad65b)

Comment: Yeah, nice, but the problem here is that this doesn't appear to work on MySQL 5.7 as tagged in the question!