# MySQL merge 2 result sets excluding records in the first

Tags: mysql, performance, mysql-5.7

I have the following table *tbl_crps*, note that the column *crp* occurs more than one time, but *id* and *starts_on* will always differ in records with the same *crp*.

```
id |  crp | starts_on  |
------------------
1  |  20  | 2020-02-09 |
2  |  31  | 2019-06-30 |
3  |  20  | 2018-01-10 |
4  |  31  | 2021-07-28 |
5  |  58  | 2022-01-15 |
6  |  58  | 2025-02-19 |
```

I need to exctract the records with the following conditions:

1. If for *crp* one or more records with past *starts_on* exist, then the one with the greatest id among those records with that *crp* (the ones with past date) must be returned
2. If for *crp* no records exist with past date, then the one with the greatest id among all the records with that *crp*

I can successfully select records matching the first condition with the following.

`SELECT * FROM tbl_crps 
AND id IN (SELECT MAX(b.id) FROM tbl_crps b WHERE b.starts_on <= "2020-10-02")`

Will return records with ids 3 and 2.

What I need to achieve is adding to the result those records which *starts_on* is not in the past and which *crp* is not in the first result set.

Is it possible? Would this be a clean way?

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_crps a
WHERE id IN (
     SELECT MAX(a.id) FROM tbl_crps a WHERE a.starts_on <= "2020-10-02"
 )
UNION
(
    SELECT * FROM tbl_crps b
        WHERE id IN (
             SELECT MAX(c.id) FROM tbl_crps c WHERE c.starts_on > "2020-10-02"
             AND c.crp NOT IN (
                  SELECT d.crp FROM tbl_crps d
                  WHERE id IN (
                       SELECT MAX(e.id) FROM tbl_crps e WHERE e.starts_on <= "2020-10-02")
                   )
        )
)
```

I'm using MySQL 5.7

Comment: Your query probably could be improved with ORDER BY and LIMIT clauses, and smells of a RIGHT JOIN

Comment: Just the value with same CRP

Comment: @HeadWizardLocke yes, I also thought about a join with a limit, but I can't figure out...I'll try something...

Comment: FYI, 2020-10-02 is October 2, not Feb 10.

Comment: @Barmar I can guarantee that on my DB that is Feb 10. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Test

```sql
SELECT id, crp, starts_on
FROM tbl_crps
NATURAL JOIN (SELECT crp, MAX(id) id
              FROM tbl_crps
              WHERE starts_on < CURRENT_DATE
              GROUP BY crp) x
UNION ALL
SELECT id, crp, starts_on
FROM tbl_crps
NATURAL JOIN (SELECT crp, MAX(id) id
              FROM tbl_crps
              GROUP BY crp
              HAVING MIN(starts_on) >= CURRENT_DATE) x;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=acb7a67d2f4c62e3a8301d3137227d7f)

Comment: Thanks Akina! It works! And it looks a lot better than mine!

Answer (score 1):

Ok for the moment I managed to get the desired results. I was just missing some `GROUP BY` here and there

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_crps a
WHERE id IN (
     SELECT MAX(a.id) FROM tbl_crps a WHERE a.starts_on <= "2020-10-02"
     GROUP BY a.crp
 )
UNION
(
    SELECT * FROM tbl_crps b
        WHERE id IN (
             SELECT MAX(c.id) FROM tbl_crps c WHERE c.starts_on > "2020-10-02"
             AND c.crp NOT IN (
                  SELECT d.crp FROM tbl_crps d
                  WHERE id IN (
                       SELECT MAX(e.id) FROM tbl_crps e WHERE e.starts_on <= "2020-10-02" 
                       GROUP BY e.crp)
                   )
             GROUP BY c.crp
             )
)
```

Fiddle, which includes Akina's attempt

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=dd37a7640d1556c624ba1ebd36192ecd